# MVC 2 Entity Framework View Model Insert

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

This is driving me crazy.  Hopefully my question makes sense...

I'm using MVC 2 and Entity Framework 1 and am trying to insert a new record with two navigation properties.

I have a SQL table, Categories, that has a lookup table CategoryTypes and another self-referencing lookup CategoryParent.  EF makes two nav properties on my Category model, one called Parent and another called CategoryType, both instances of their respective models.

On my view that creates the new Category, I have two dropdowns, one for the CategoryType and another for the ParentCategory.  When I try and insert the new Category WITHOUT the ParentCategory, which allows nulls, everything is fine. As soon as I add the ParentCategory, the insert fails, and oddly (or so I think) complains about the CategoryType in the form of this error:

0 related 'CategoryTypes' were found. 1 'CategoryTypes' is expected.

When I step through, I can verifiy that both ID properties coming in on the action method parameter are correct.  I can also verify that when I go to the db to get the CategoryType and ParentCategory with the ID's, the records are being pulled fine.  Yet it fails on SaveChanges().

All that I can see is that my CategoryParent dropdownlistfor in my view, is somehow causing the insert to bomb.

Please see my comments in my httpPost Create action method.

My view model looks like this:

```
public class EditModel
{
    public Category MainCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryType> CategoryTypesList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> ParentCategoriesList { get; set; }
}
```

My Create action methods look like this:

```
// GET: /Categories/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new EditModel()
        {
            CategoryTypesList = _db.CategoryTypeSet.ToList(),
            ParentCategoriesList = _db.CategorySet.ToList()
        });
    }

    // POST: /Categories/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category mainCategory)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(new EditModel()
            {
                MainCategory = mainCategory,
                CategoryTypesList = _db.CategoryTypeSet.ToList(),
                ParentCategoriesList = _db.CategorySet.ToList()
            });

        mainCategory.CategoryType = _db.CategoryTypeSet.First(ct => ct.Id == mainCategory.CategoryType.Id);

        // This db call DOES get the correct Category, but fails on _db.SaveChanges().
        // Oddly the error is related to CategoryTypes and not Category.
        // Entities in 'DbEntities.CategorySet' participate in the 'FK_Categories_CategoryTypes' relationship.
        // 0 related 'CategoryTypes' were found. 1 'CategoryTypes' is expected.
        //mainCategory.Parent = _db.CategorySet.First(c => c.Id == mainCategory.Parent.Id);

        // If I just use the literal ID of the same Category,
        // AND comment out the CategoryParent dropdownlistfor in the view, all is fine.
        mainCategory.Parent = _db.CategorySet.First(c => c.Id == 2);

        _db.AddToCategorySet(mainCategory);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is my Create form on the view :

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.Parent.Id) %>
            <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainCategory.Parent.Id, new SelectList(Model.ParentCategoriesList, "Id", "Name")) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.Parent.Id) %>
        </div>

        <div>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.CategoryType.Id) %>
            <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainCategory.CategoryType.Id, new SelectList(Model.CategoryTypesList, "Id", "Name"))%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.CategoryType.Id)%>
        </div>

        <div>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.Name) %>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainCategory.Name)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.Name)%>
        </div>

        <div>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.Description)%>
            <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MainCategory.Description)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.Description)%>
        </div>

        <div>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.SeoName)%>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainCategory.SeoName, new { @class = "large" })%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.SeoName)%>
        </div>

        <div>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.HasHomepage)%>
            <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MainCategory.HasHomepage)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.HasHomepage)%>
        </div>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Maybe I've just been staying up too late playing with MVC 2? :)  Please let me know if I'm not being clear enough.

**Some things I've changed since asking this question.  I think I'm close?**

My new Create action method:

```
        private DbEntities _db = new DbEntities();

    // POST: /Categories/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category mainCategory)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(new EditModel()
            {
                MainCategory = mainCategory,
                CategoryTypesList = _db.CategoryTypeSet.ToList(),
                ParentCategoriesList = _db.CategorySet.ToList()
            });

        int parentId = 2; // Accessories in db.
        short typeId = 1; // Product type in db.
        mainCategory.ParentReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("DbEntities.CategorySet", "Id", parentId);
        mainCategory.CategoryTypeReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("DbEntities.CategoryTypeSet", "Id", typeId);

        _db.AddToCategorySet(mainCategory);     
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I've also commented out my two dropdownlists so those properties on "mainCategory" don't get instantiated.

So, with the 2 nav properties null now, I use two literals for the Id's and it works perfectly. Ultimately, I want to use the Id's of Parent and CategoryType from mainCategory, but this seems to not work.  Probably a good reason I'm not aware of?

Comment: have you set a breakpoint right after you set the CategoryType and confirmed beyond a doubt that the property has been populated?

Comment: Hi Dave. Yes, I can confirm via breakpoint that mainCategory.CategoryType is getting populated with just the Id from the form submit, and then with a parent Category from the _db.CategoryTypeSet call.

Comment: Try calling `AddToCategorySet` *before* setting `CategoryType`; does that help?

Comment: Hey Craig.  The CategoryType on my Category is not nullable, so this gives me a cannot insert null value error.  I feel I must tell you, your other posts here have helped me NUMEROUS times, so thanks!

When my action method parameter mainCategory.Parent gets instantiated, either from my form post or in my controller, it somehow causes this error.  I'm beginning to think that it is somehow related to the strongly typed html helpers, as I've done this before with no problems in MVC1.  That or I'm just overlooking something really stupid.

Comment: You still need to set `CategoryType`. Just call `AddToCategorySet` first. That won't give you a null error, as long as you set `CategoryType` before calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I have tried moving AddToCategorySet just before setting the CategoryType which is just before calling SaveChanges and I get "Cannot insert NULL value into the column 'Name' table dbo.CategoryTypes."  On stepping though, I can verify that category.CategoryType is getting populated with a CategoryType.

Comment: It appears the `EntityState` of the `CategoryType` is wrong. The EF thinks you're adding the type rather than reusing it. This suggests that there is either more than one context or you've changed the `MergeOption`. It would be good to see the rest of the code which deals with `_db`.

Comment: About the context, all I know is that I'm using a single context in the form of a private member in my controller.  I edited my inital question with some more info I hope?  See after the line "Some things I've changed since asking this question. I think I'm close?"

Comment: The IDs are `int`s. A certain value will either work or not, no matter where it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting the EntityReference like

```
mainCategory.CategoryTypeReference.EntityKey = new EnityKey("YourEntities", "Id", mainCategory.CategoryType.Id);
```

that way you wont have to load your CategoryType and it might resolve your problem.

**EDIT**: The sample i posted is not complete, sorry, here is what you should do

```
int parentId = mainCategory.Parent.Id; 
short typeId = mainCategory.CategoryType.Id;

mainCategory.Parent = null;
mainCategory.CategoryType = null;
mainCategory.ParentReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("DbEntities.CategorySet", "Id", parentId); 
mainCategory.CategoryTypeReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("DbEntities.CategoryTypeSet", "Id", typeId);
```

Comment: I do like this way of adding a foreign key for EF version 1.0, but unfortunately, it behaves the same way on insert, but only when I add a CategoryType along with a parent Category. If I omit the parent Category, both ways work fine. Your way being the most efficient for sure.

Comment: See my edit, forgot to tell that you have to set the Parent and CategoryType to null, that way there won't be problem with reference they could have

Comment: Welp, that did the trick!!!  I basically just did what you said here, thinking that it was a little odd that I have to set those nav properties to null. But it works!  In my edit method I don't have to null those properties, so I guess this only goes for inserts.  In any matter, THANK YOU moi_meme!!!!!!!!!  ...And everyone who took a stab at this!